# Express and Request make Chrome download a file instead of serving it

Tags: node.js, express, request

I want to serve a remote HTML so I am:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.header('Content-Type', 'text/html');

    request('https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/...o/html%2Findex.html?generation=1475649807769000&alt=media')
        .pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

1. Downloading it using [Request](https://github.com/request/request) module.
2. Piping it to express' **res**.

In Chrome, instead of seeing the HTML, Chrome downloads it. How come?

[image]

Comment: Probably because you're piping the response headers from the request directly to the browser, and those headers contain either a `content-disposition` header, and/or they overwrite your `content-type` header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're piping the result of the HTTP request directly to your response, any headers that get set by the remote server will be copied verbatim, including headers that may force a download, like `content-disposition`.

You already came up with a good solution yourself:

```
request
    .get(URL)
    .on('response', (response) => {
        delete response.headers['content-disposition']
    })
    .pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this attribute to the header response:

```
res.header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename= "' + encodeURI(file_name) +'"' );
```